# css: allow any width but set as square

Tags: html, css

On my site, I have several images that are user profile images. At different places the picture is a different size, but I want it to always have a rounded edge and be always square.

Currently I have:

```
img.profile_pic {border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0px;}
```

and then use other classes like `wide_150` to make it `150px` wide.

Is there any way to force the picture to be square using css?

Comment: javascript something like width = height, or vice versa?

Comment: So what's the issue with what you have now?

Comment: @Randy Currently, I have the style that sets the border radius. What I am trying to do is create a UNIVERSAL RULE for all profile pictures to be square, and allow other classes to dictate the actual size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<script>
function setAspectRatio() {
    var widthOfUserImage1 = document.getElementById('UserImage1').style.width;
    document.getElementById('UserImage1').style.height = widthOfUserImage1;
    }

window.onload = setAspectRatio();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will help you. https://selbie.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/scale-crop-and-center-an-image-with-correct-aspect-ratio-in-html-and-javascript/ 
There is an example in css and then a better way in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the user profile image as background. Set the width and height to a square apply `border-radius`.

Use `background-size: contain;` to draw the profile image inside the square. The radius on the border will clip the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick:

```css
    div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    border-radius: 50%; 
    }
```

```html
<div style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150)"></div>
```

Just use a style as a 'src' of your image.